# can i correctly finish an android app in Kotlin, when i swipe it out?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dismiss

I hope, I can formulate my question correctly and understandable.

When I write an Android App in Kotlin, I normally have a button to close the app and for example finish it with writing a file or something like that.
Now, sometimes I don't finish it with the button, but swipe it out. Then, the file is not wirtten..

Is there a Kotlin statement to catch the "swipe out" and perform some code? When I Inflate another view, at the end I have a dismiss-statement or dismiss.listener and can do some code.

example:

```
dialog.dismiss()   or popupwindow.dismiss()
```

So question: is there a dismiss.app or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

When your app's `Activity` is destroyed (either by the user swiping it away, or the system killing the app to free up some resources) [it goes through the usual lifecycle steps](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy), ending with `onDestroy`.

These steps also get pushed to any lifecycle-aware components that are observing that activity's lifecycle, including `Fragment`s (like a `DialogFragment`) - so that [will also get an `onDestroy()` call](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_destroyed). Fragments can be destroyed at other times too, but you can look at the activity's lifecycle to see what's going on there if you need to.

---

But really, as a general rule you want to save data in something like `onStop()`, when the activity/fragment is going to stop being visible, i.e. it's going into the background. That's a good time to make sure you've saved all your important data and state, because the user may not be coming back, and you can't be *sure* `onDestroy` will be neatly called (e.g. there could be a crash, or the phone might suddenly lose power).

**Don't** rely on persisting data with the `onSaveInstanceState()` callback though - that's intended for saving UI state, and if the user backs out of the app / swipes it away, that's counted as a fresh start for the next time they load the app, [so `onSaveInstanceState` won't be called](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes#back) (since the UI state isn't being saved). Use `onStop` instead (or `onPause` if you like - have a look at those links for more info on what the difference is)